# Ĉu eblas uzi «kie» kiel relativan pronomon en abstrakta senco?

Tags: pronouns

Ekzemple, ĉu frazo kiel la jena estas ĝusta?

> Catan estas tabulludo **kie** oni konstruas vilaĝojn sur insulo.

En ĉi tiu frazo Catan ne priskribas lokon, do la uzo de *kie* estas abstrakta. En la angla oni nature povus uzi *where* en tia frazo, sed ĉu tio eblas en Esperanto? Se ne, kiu estas la ĝusta pronomo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ĝenerale jes.

La [plej rilata sekcio en PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/aliaj_ki-vortoj.html) donas tri ekzemplojn de uzoj de *kie* anstataŭ *en kiu(j), ĉe kiu(j)*: (1) *artikolojn, kie estis videble*; (2) *bieno, kie floris rozoj*, (3) *ne troviĝas, kie sidi*. Rimarku, ke tiuj citaĵoj koncernas nur fizikajn lokojn. Tamen, mi trovis bonan ekzemplon de Zamenhofa uzo de *kie* por tute abstrakta loko:

> *La diferenco en la aĝo de ambaŭ knabinoj povis esti ne pli ol kvar jaroj. Sed Grace, kiel ofte **en tiaj okazoj, kie ne estas patrino**, zorganta pri ambaŭ (la edzino de la doktoro mortis), en la zorganta amo al ŝia pli juna fratino ŝajnis pli maljuna, ol ŝi estis...* (el *La batalo de l' vivo*)

Mi ne certas, ke la frazo citita de vi estas vere imitinda. *Kie* en tiu loko donas impreson de malpreciza vortgesto. Mi mem skribus: *tabulludo pri konstruado de vilaĝoj sur insulo* aŭ *tabulludo kies celo estas...*.